# PHP regex number formatting

Tags: php, regex

My regex strips all points away except the last one. Great!
But what I wish, is only to strip "thousand" separators, not the "float" ones. I suppose floats ends with one or two digits.
I cannot change the input format.

Any idea how to extend that regex?

```
<?php

print_r(preg_replace('/\.(?=.*\.)/', '', "1.234.20")); // works
echo "<hr />";
print_r(preg_replace('/\.(?=.*\.)/', '', "1234.20")); // works
echo "<hr />";
print_r(preg_replace('/\.(?=.*\.)/', '', "1234.2")); // works
echo "<hr />";
print_r(preg_replace('/\.(?=.*\.)/', '', "1234.217")); // works
echo "<hr />";
print_r(preg_replace('/\.(?=.*\.)/', '', "1.000.234.20")); // works
echo "<hr />";
print_r(preg_replace('/\.(?=.*\.)/', '', "1.234")); // buuuh, 1234 would be correct

?>
```

Comment: why would "1234" be correct on last exemple ? if you remove every point but the last, you get "1.234", not "1234"... What is the rule ?

Comment: I'm confused. "My regex strips all points away except the last one" -- stripping away all dots in `1.234` except the last one is, `1.234`.

Comment: @Random Beat me to it by 1 second lol

Comment: the last example should be 1234, because the point is a thousand seperator and not a decimal seperator.

Comment: You rule says **match a dot if it's followed by some characters and dot**. `1.234` doesn't fit that rule.

Comment: @noob i know and that's the problem :) I need a rule that works for previous examples but still removes a thousand seperator.

Comment: How would you determine whether 123.456 is a float or integer?

Comment: @Mike: Then you should specify in your question what you are trying to match and what your current regex is doing. It's hard to make out why you are using `.` as separator ? Usually `,` is used.

Comment: @Random a float has only two digits after the seperator in this case

Comment: @Random yeah but i can't change that.

Comment: @noob Depends on the locale. Some countries use `.` as a thousands separator, however in that case they use a `,` as a decimal point. Like `1.234,56`.

Comment: Argh. Too many Mikes here.

Comment: @Mike a `,` is not used in any way here

Comment: `"\.[0-9]{2}$"` does not remove the thousand seperator here `1.234`

Comment: Isn't it possible to get your input in a better way? Using a dot as thousand and decimal separator is just.. meh..

Comment: @SebastianProske yeah it is...

Comment: What about replacing `\.([0-9]{3})` with `$1` ?

Comment: @Random that seams to match in this case. thanks!

Comment: If it resolves the issue, please accept my answer and my edit (and purge unneeded comments)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you assume every thousand separator is followed by exactly 3 digits, you can do it this way.
This excludes the case where a float is ending with 3 or more digits...

```
<?php
print_r(preg_replace('/\.([0-9]{3})/', '$1', "1.234.20")); // 1234.20
echo "<hr />";
print_r(preg_replace('/\.([0-9]{3})/', '$1', "1234.20")); // 1234.20
echo "<hr />";
print_r(preg_replace('/\.([0-9]{3})/', '$1', "1234.2")); // 1234.2
echo "<hr />";
print_r(preg_replace('/\.([0-9]{3})/', '$1', "1234.217")); // 1234217
echo "<hr />";
print_r(preg_replace('/\.([0-9]{3})/', '$1', "1.000.234.20")); // 1000234.20
echo "<hr />";
print_r(preg_replace('/\.([0-9]{3})/', '$1', "1.234")); // 1234
?>
```